# Align environment: second alignment "left-justified"?

Tags: align

How can I do something like

```
\begin{align*}
b &= cq_1+r_1, & 0 < r_1 < c, \\
c &= r_1q_2+r_2, & 0 < r_2 < r_1, \\
r_{j-2} &= r_{j-1}q_j+r_j, & 0 < r_j < r_{j-1},
\end{align*}
```

such that all of the zero's are aligned to the left? Mine defaults to align on the right...

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `&` between the two statements on each line.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Ah! Thank you. Is there a way to make the space between each "column" smaller?

Comment: There's no natural way to do that using the `align` environment. But check out `alignat`.

Comment: @CharlesStaats That is much better than the align environment and does pretty much exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Regarding your formula, I suggest treating the conditions as a secondset of formula and align them as well: `b &= cq_1+r_1, & 0 < r_1 &< c,`

Comment: @CharlesStaats fancy making your comments into a complete answer? :)

Comment: @Toscho Thanks! I did not know that I could do that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternate way to approach the answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}[2013-09-11]
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\Longstack[r]{b\\c\\r_{j-2}}
\mathrel{\Longstack[l]{= cq_1+r_1,\\= r_1q_2+r_2,\\= r_{j-1}q_j+r_j,}}
\qquad\qquad\qquad
\Longstack[l]{0 < r_1 < c,\\0 < r_2 < r_1,\\0 < r_j < r_{j-1},}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]